# Perl : Creating hash using array value

Tags: perl

I'm bit new to perl and working on a small script which basically reads a file having timelines in a slightly unstructured manner something like -

```
Test/Month/January
Test/Month/February
Mock/Month/August
Practical/Month/June
Result/Month/October
```

Basically I want to read it and frame a hash which will be segregated based on the events(Test/Mock/Practical/Result) and the values will be maintained as an array. So for the above file when I run my script it should output the following hash -

```
{
    Timetable => { 'Test' => ['January', 'February'], 'Mock' => ['August'], 'Practical' => ['June'], 'Result' => ['October'] } 
}
```

Timetable will be the outer hash which will have the whole data. Suggestions and help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please show your code?

Comment: I've an incomplete code where I'm just reading the content using a file descriptor and trying to grep the events, was not making sense to add here. @vkk05

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the below script, which would help you.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;

while(<DATA>){
        chomp $_;
        my @data = split("/", $_);
        push (@{$hash{$data[0]}}, $data[2]);
}

print Dumper(\%hash);

__DATA__
Test/Month/January
Test/Month/February
Mock/Month/August
Practical/Month/June
Result/Month/October
```

Result:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Practical' => [
                           'June'
                         ],
          'Result' => [
                        'October'
                      ],
          'Test' => [
                      'January',
                      'February'
                    ],
          'Mock' => [
                      'August'
                    ]
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution would be to read each line and split on `/`, check that there are 3 elements in the returned array and then check that the middle element is equal to `Month`. If so, push the last element into an array which is mapped via the first element in a hash varible.

Example:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %H; # first element is key - map to an array

while(<>) {
    chomp;
    @_ = split(m:/:,$_); # Test/Month/January

    # check that there are 3 elements and that the middle is `Month`
    # then push to the mapped array:
    push @{$H{$_[0]}}, $_[2] if(@_ == 3 && $_[1] eq 'Month');
}

print Dumper(\%H);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Practical' => [
                           'June'
                         ],
          'Test' => [
                      'January',
                      'February'
                    ],
          'Result' => [
                        'October'
                      ],
          'Mock' => [
                      'August'
                    ]
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just read the input line by line, split each line on `/Month/` and push the month to an anonymous array stored under the event key in a hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $h;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my ($event, $month) = split m{/Month/};
    push @{ $h->{Timetable}{$event} }, $month;
}
```